# Determinants of upper-left submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

My linear algebra textbook (Strang's 5th Edition), states that one does not need row exchanges to find the determinant of a matrix $A$ by elimination if the determinants of all the upper-left submatrices of $A$ are not equal to $0$ (if $det(A_{k}) \neq 0$ for all upper-left submatrices $A_k$).

More concisely, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\newline a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\newline a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$,

then the upperleft submatrix is $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \newline a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$

Can somebody help me understand why this statement is true? Proofs are also welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Does Strang really write *"determinants of all the upper-left submatrices"*? The standard terminology is "leading principal minors".

Comment: Yes. He writes verbatim "We don't need row exchanges when all the upper left submatrices have $det(A_k) \neq 0$".

Answer (score 2):

Since $\det(a_{11}) = a_{11} \neq 0$, we can bring the matrix to the form

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0 & * & * \\ 0 & * & * \end{pmatrix}$$

by just multiplying row I by a scalar, and subtracting multiples of row I form row II and III. Now, imagine that the entry in the (2,2)-position was zero (meaning we would need to interchange rows II and III to proceed). Then, by applying the same row operations we have just done to the submatrix $A_2$, we would find that

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \sim A_2. $$

But the only thing that our row operations can do is multiply the determinant by a nonzero scalar, so this gives a contradiction. (The determinant of the matrix on the left is zero, while the one on the right is non-zero by assumption.)

So, we can proceed by eliminating the second column, to get a matrix of the form:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0 & 1 & * \\ 0 & 0 & * \end{pmatrix}. $$

Again, the element in the (3,3)-position is nonzero (Why?). You can now calculate the determinant of the matrix by looking at what numbers you multiplied by to make the (1,1) and (2,2)-entries into a one to find the determinant of the matrix. Note that you didn't need to interchange any rows.

NOTE: I don't think this particular statement is that useful in practice, since you could also just apply the algorithm, and then interchange rows when necessary. It's quite unnecessary to compute determinants of the submatrices in advance.

Comment: I'm confused about the part where you mention "matrices on the left" and "matrices on the right". Where are the left and right matrices? Also what does $det(A_2)=0$ contradict?

Comment: I'm talking about the two matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} .$ By the argument in the second paragraph, those matrices are row-equivalent, while the first matrix has determinant zero, and the second one has determinant nonzero by your assumption about upper-left submatrices.

Comment: IF the element in the (2,2)-position after the first row reduction would be zero, THEN you obtain $\det(A_2) = 0$. Hence, that element is nonzero, and we don't need an interchange of rows to continue.

Comment: Ah I see. One last thing - why is $a_{33}$ nonzero? Shouldn't its value be irrelevant, as the 3 $\times$ 3 submatrix of $A$ would be itself - hence why this submatrix is irrelevant. If $a_{33}$ was zero surely you still wouldn't need row exchanges because there wouldn't be any rows to exchange and elimination would just breakdown.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that the determinant of $A$ (which you could call $A_3$) is also nonzero. That would imply that the element in the (3,3)-position is also nonzero. It depends if you count $A$ itself as a submatrix or not. It doesn't influence the argument in any way luckily.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks for the clarification!